# Why can't console.log be called using .call()

Tags: javascript

The below code returns a pop-up window with 'hello'.

```
alert.call(this, 'hello');
```

But the below code returns an error "TypeError: Illegal invocation".

```
console.log.call(this, 'hello');
```

What is the difference in the implements of alert and console.log?

Comment: @Teemu I think he wants to know why the 2nd yields that error :)

Comment: see more about [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Then why not ask about it?

Comment: @Teemu I'm sorry about that..

Comment: console functions will be bound to console: https://codereview.chromium.org/1859293002

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`alert` is a global method (`window.alert`). If you call it `alert.call(this)`, `this` is the window object.

Because log is a method in the console object, it expects `this` to be the console object itself, but you are still calling it with `this`(`window`), so you get an error.

Running `console.log.call(console, 'test')` will work fine.